# Dynamic web project missing in STS

Tags: eclipse, web, spring-tool-suite

I am facing one issue with  Spring tool suite 4, I don't see "Dynamic web project" option. I want to create one dynamic web project but I do not find this option in my Spring tool suite. How to install those external tool in Spring tool suite, however I got few link i.e http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars for eclipse, should I use this link for Spring tool suite as well?

Answer (score 7):

Solve this issue in Spring Tool Suite 4

Tested with 4.15.1 RELEASE

Go to **Help -> Install New Software..**

Enter eclipse software repo link (**https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest**) in **Work with** input box.

You will get the list of available software. **Filter the list** by searching for Java EE related software. Search something like "java ee" to make things easier.

Choose **Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools** from the filtered list and proceed further with installation.

You may need to restart the STS IDE to install the update properly.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this on STS 4.x.x

1. Go to Install New Software.
2. Select the main Eclipse update site for 2019-03 ( if not added, you must click o add button and paste this URL: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2019-03 on both fields)
3. search for **m2e-wtp** There are four extensions showing up and you should install the ones you prefer.
4. Restart your IDE

see https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/96#issuecomment-484522744 on  **martinlippert** comment

Comment: Even after doing this, dynamic web module was still missing for me.

Comment: After installing the latest version, "Version: 4.4.0.RELEASE" (Build Id: 201909171436), everything worked. I got perspective J2EE and project facets "Dynamic Web Module".

Comment: search for "Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools" install it. m2e is maven for eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/96#issuecomment-484522744

Short version: fixed in Spring Tools 4.2.2 (coming in late May 2019), workaround is to install the m2e-wtp features from the main Eclipse update repo into an existing Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse install.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you dont see dynamic web project in File->New and also in other
2. Then go to help -> install new software
3. copy paste this http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars/ and click enter
   if it is the first time then it take lot of time to download depends upon the internet
   Once it get started downloading a pop will appear as trust click on that
4. After downloading make sure to restart STS and check whether dynamic web project is showing or not
5. check in file->new or else check in Others

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to create jsp file in STS & follow below steps & it worked for me.

1. Go to "Help"
2. click on "Install new software"
3. Select all available sites
4. Select XML, JAVA EE, OSGi enterprise development form the drop down list
5. Select eclipse web development tools

And then finish and you will be able to create web project

Answer (score 0):

Best Solution is Download latest version of STS and after installation
Go to "Help"
click on "Install new software"
Select all available sites
Select XML, JAVA EE, OSGi enterprise development form the drop down list
Select eclipse web development tools

You are issue will definitely resolve.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).