# unable to create dynamic web project in spring tool suite 4.2.1

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

Previously I used to create dynamic web project on eclipse but I want to make project on spring tool suite i.e 4.2.1 & I've never used it before, so does anybody knows how to create a dynamic web project in Spring Tool Suite 4.2.1 or a reference to where I can get, as I've been trying to create one since 4 hours. Please help me.

Comment: And nobody in the company was able to lead/manage/guide you? I'd personally look for another company as you will learn nothing this way.

Comment: I haven't asked them yet @BalusC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referring to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56090961/dynamic-web-project-missing-in-sts)

To solve this on STS 4.x.x

1. Click on Help.
2. Go to Install New Software.
3. Select the main Eclipse update site for 2019-09 ( if not added, you must click o add button and paste this URL:http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2019-09/ on both fields).
4. search for **m2e-wtp** which will be in the last. There are four extensions showing up and you should install the ones you prefer.
5. Restart your IDE

see https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/96#issuecomment-484522744 on **martinlippert** comment..

I've added link of latest current version.

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

The Spring Tools 4.2.1 for Eclipse distribution didn't contain the necessary features and extensions to create dynamic web projects. This got added for later Spring Tools 4 versions. So the easiest solution would be to install a fresh distribution of the latest Spring Tools 4.3.2 for Eclipse and go from there.

As an alternative, you could also install the missing pieces into an existing Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse installation via `Install New Software`, then selecting the main Eclipse repository from the dropdown list, waiting for the list of features to appear, and selecting the features you are missing.